# What was the point of testing carbonite-freezing technology on Han Solo?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

Darth Vader tested carbonite-freezing technology on Han Solo because he didn't want to kill Luke who was precious to the emperor. But, why was it necessary? Wasn't it already a tested and proven technology? Even Darth Vader (when he was Anakin) himself used it along with others decades ago (*Star Wars: The Clone Wars* S03E18).

Comment: How else was Lucas going to get Leia to admit that she loved Han?  And how else could he let her know that he knew?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the scene referred to in the question, the commander, Obi-Wan and Anakin himself all talk about this idea as though it is unproven and being completely improvised.

Anakin (and the Ugnaught operators) and [the Krath](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Krath) were the only ones to have been known to use [carbon freezing chambers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Carbon-freezing_chamber) to freeze living beings.

So while Vader knew it *could* be done, the chamber device and chamber probably still had to be calibrated and adjusted to the correct settings so that it *would* be done correctly.

Comment: Also, Vader probably wanted to play with the carbon freezing chamber.

Comment: Unable to understand first paragraph... Wasn't Republic officially used carbon freezing chamber to freeze living beings in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* season 3?

Comment: @SachinShekhar IIRC the SW canon policy is that the films over-ride everything else, so if that episode of *The Clone Wars* contradict the film in some way, then the episode was wrong.

Comment: @SachinShekhar, see the edit to the answer. Judging from the reactions, this did not seem to be a common use for the freezing chambers by the Republic.

Comment: Okay.. for the first time, it was unproven. My question is: Why was it unproven for second time?

Comment: 1) The Clone Wars is T-Canon, so one could argue that it is NOT proven at the time of ESB. 2) I never said it was "unproven" the second time. He agreed that it would be a good idea to test the selected settings on someone else and make sure that it wouldn't kill Luke. If you seriously don't understand why he might want to do that, I really don't know what else to tell you.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - generally it takes more than 1 experiment to greenlight a dangerous human-use technology :)

Comment: Even if the process and technique had been proven, **this equipment** hadn't been proven. It's the difference between knowing that Crysis 3 will run on a computer, versus knowing that it will run on **this** computer.

Comment: They seem to be treating it like drinking from an industrial water hose--it's not that the idea of humans drinking water is untested or inherently unsafe, it's that equipment used for manufacturing/processing may be bad for humans to use (trace chemicals, harsh pressures/temperatures, etc.)

Comment: The video died  :(

Comment: I'll dig around tonight and see if I can find another copy..

Answer (score 15):

## No one says that it hasn't been done before.  Vader's only uncertainty is in how powerful the freezing unit is.

Lando cautiously asserts,

> "We only use this facility for carbon freezing.  If you put him [Luke] in there, it might kill him."

Vader responds with,

> "I don't wish for the Emperor's prize to be damaged. We'll test it first."

I am using the dialogue as it appears in the official [*Empire Strikes Back* novelization](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pevF1lrz9TQC&pg=RA1-PA178&lpg=RA1-PA178&dq=star+wars+trilogy+kahn+carbon+freezing&source=bl&ots=tDx1VdTdLv&sig=Pd8ZrpeZ2AEopRd3a9ts94GySlM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKvKOx0NDKAhVC2B4KHRC4Ar0Q6AEIJDAE#v=onepage&q=star%20wars%20trilogy%20kahn%20carbon%20freezing&f=false).

The novelization gives an insight into Vader's thinking:

> **He knew a way to find out just how powerful this freezing unit was.**

This test, of course, involves Han:

> "Bring in Captain Solo."

The fact that Vader wants this done (freezing Luke in carbon as a means of transportation) could be inspired by his experiences in the Clone Wars.  The novelization suggests that, as far as Vader is concerned, **the only uncertainty is in how powerful the unit is**, which is why Han is subjected to the procedure.

Comment: Oh, so the answer is not "because _The Clone Wars_ hadn't been written yet"? Neat.

Answer (score 13):

During the actual scene where Vader talks about freezing Luke, Lando expresses concern:

> Lando: Lord Vader, we only use this facility for carbon freezing. If you put him in there it might kill him.
>
> Darth Vader: I do not want the Emperor's prize damaged. We will test it on Captain Solo.

This leads one to believe that this is still a fairly experimental technology when it comes to freezing humanoids. But, in answer to your question, the reason for testing it on Han was to make sure he lived. In theory, if he lived, so would Luke.

Comment: I think this quote doesn't necessarily imply that the technology is experimental.  Perhaps Cloud City, as a mining outpost, regularly carbon-froze inanimate objects.  Lando's concern could be that his facility is industrial rather than medical grade.

Comment: @Simon: I put that line in there, because when we first saw it, my friends and I all thought that meant it was experimental and unproven.

Comment: @Simon If answerer has rejected your suggestion, add your answer with the movie quote. You've got point.

Comment: Lando's quote is pretty imprecise.  Technically what Vader is asking is carbon freezing.  But inference is that Vader's request is not what they typically use it for and so the outcome is uncertain.  IE, they don't use this on organics.  And why would they?  They aren't slavers.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of storing and transporting cargo that are not necessarily suited for living beings. Would you like to be stuck in an airplane's baggage hold instead of its cabin?

The freezing process was most likely NEVER used for living beings, even though technically it was possible. It was only used for preserving perishable items for shipping. Naturally, using it on living beings would cause some trepidation.

Comment: Why is everyone ignoring last sentence of my question?

Comment: Was it a different model? That might explain it, as I haven't watched the Clone War episode you're referring to, Sachin. Perhaps it was the type, the process, or even the ingredient that was unproven, not the concept.

Comment: @SachinShekhar because you seem to think that just because he did it ONE time, 20 years ago, he knows the exact right settings and calibrations on another device to make sure this goes off without a hitch. He *may* also just want to prove to Fett that the concept works.

Answer (score 2):

I also felt there was some conflict between the tension in episode V (about whether or not Solo would survive the freezing process) and the generous use of carbon freezing in some of the newer productions.

But this isn't an outright contradiction if you look closely at this conversation between Darth Vader and Lando:

Vader: "This FACILITY IS CRUDE but it should be enough to freeze Skywalker."
Lando: "We only use this for carbon freezing. You put him in there it could kill him!"
Vader: "I do not want the Emperor's prize damaged. We will test it on Captain Solo."

So Vader's concern is the "crudeness" of the facility. But one could argue that the ease of carbon freezing in other productions undermines the suspense of episode V. We are supposed to be worried that Han Solo might die, right? In a universe where people are being frozen all the time, we are not so worried about Han (but that's just my opinion).

*Alternate/ additional interpretation: Lando is trying to thwart Vader's efforts by coming up with excuses, but he knows the freezing will probably work... and Vader also knows the freezing will probably work but he is being overprotective toward his son, because subconsciously he cares about him.

Comment: You posted this as an answer, but it doesn't seem to address the actual question: _"What was the point of testing carbonite-freezing technology on Han Solo?"_ I believe you were instead responding to another user's comment, regarding a possible contradiction between _The Empire Strikes Back_ and  _The Clone Wars_ series, but the answer box is meant for posting answers to the question, not responding to comments.

Comment: @LogicDictates - Yes it does! I said, "Vader's concern is the crudeness of the facility". I even put it in all caps! There is arguably a contradiction in star wars which is the basis for the users question. You have to read beyond my first paragraph which is simply an acknowledgement of the validity of the question. My alternate answer in the final paragraph also addresses the question.

Answer (score -2):

The real answer is the movie came out 30 years before the cartoon.  The people writing the cartoon didn't remember/care why Solo was frozen.

Many times when you have several writers working on a work of fiction there are inconsistencies.

Comment: Actually They wanted to use the chamber because it was such a powerful scene in ESB.  They were borrowing off of that for the cartoon.

Comment: I think you need to back up that statement. How do you know that they didn't care?