# How many people have undergone carbon freezing in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

We all know the story of Han Solo being a guinea pig for the planned freezing of Luke Skywalker, but how often are people "stored" in this way?

Comment: Do you want only canon answers because the books from Del Ray have a number of other carbon frozen people.  I'm not sure if they are canon

Comment: Sure, as long as this doesn't turn into a list question. I just want to know how often it happens.

Comment: mostly duplicated here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35841/what-was-the-point-of-testing-carbonite-freezing-technology-on-han-solo

Comment: @NKCampbell: This question is a little different than the one you've linked. Instead of asking why Han needed freezing, this is asking how many people have been frozen that we know of.

Comment: Right - that's why I said "mostly" instead of voting to close it :)

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't say people are "stored" this way very often. I'm sure there are instances of people being frozen in the Star Wars universe off-screen that we'll never know about because there are a lot of bad people out in the Star Wars universe. However, it has happened, in canon, prior to Han Solo being frozen.

In the Clone Wars episode [*The Citadel* (season 3, episode 18)](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-citadel-episode-guide), a team consisting of Obi-Wan Kenobi, Anakin Skywalker, Ahsoka Tano, and some clone troopers voluntarily underwent carbon freezing in order to infiltrate a planet that utilized lifeform scanners as a security precaution on incoming ships.

They were unfrozen by droids led by R2D2 when they arrived on the target planet.

By my count, this mission consists of about 8 people. Add Han Solo to the mix, and there's been 9 instances of carbon freezing people in on-screen canon.

Comment: If Anakin knew that carbonite freezing worked, having done it himself, why was Han considered a "guinea pig"?

Comment: @Paul: See [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116833/19252).

Comment: @Paul - Basically, there's a big difference between knowing the process works and knowing a particular unit is capable of it.